# Modify Streaming responses in httputil.ReverseProxy golang

Tags: go, streaming, reverse-proxy

I am trying to use ModifyResponse provided in httputil.ReverseProxy to modify a SSE/streaming type response. This is the code that I have right now for ModifyResponse :

```
func ModifyResponse(r *http.Response) error {
    bodyBytes, err := ioutil.ReadAll(r.Body)
    if err != nil {
        return fmt.Errorf("error reading response body: %v", err)
    }
    conf.Logger.Debug("response", zap.Any("resp", string(bodyBytes)))

    buf := bytes.NewBuffer(bodyBytes)
    r.Body = ioutil.NopCloser(buf)
    return nil
}
```

The goal is to continue modifying any data that's returned in the stream but with the above modify handler the stream seems to close and no more updates are received on the client side, if I remove the body manipulation part from the modify response and just keep it as:

```
func ModifyResponse(r *http.Response) error {
    return nil
}
```

the stream continues to work and new events are received on the client side. Is there any way for me to modify the stream data without closing/breaking the stream?